# How to configure base layers in Geonetwork

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork

I am trying to get an instance of Geonetwork configured but I can't get base layers to display in the Map Viewer as shown below:

[image]

I think problem has to do with the fact that I installed Geoserver before Geonetwork so the default WMS base layers that Geonetwork uses where not set up.  Is there a script somewhere that will add these or do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a file inside your installation path where you can customize your base layer/s and servers: **WEB-INF/config-gui.xml**. It contains some instruction about this configuration.

You can define base layers for both the mapSearch (the smaller one) and the mapViewer. 
Here's an example from a working Geonetwork config:

```
<mapSearch options="{    projection: 'EPSG:4326',     units: 'degrees',     restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-63,-27,-57,-22),    }">
  <layers>
     <layer server="http://wms.ign.gob.ar/geoserver/wms?" tocName="Capa Base IGN" params="{ layers: 'IGN:limite_politico_administrativo_lim,IGN:localidad',     transparent: 'true', format: 'image/png'}" options="{isBaseLayer: true}" />
  </layers>
</mapSearch>


  <mapViewer options="{    projection: 'EPSG:4326',      units: 'degrees',     restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-63,-27,-57,-22)    }">
    <layers> 
      <layer server="http://wms.ign.gob.ar/geoserver/wms?" tocName="Capa Base IGN" params="{      layers: 'IGN:limite_politico_administrativo_lim,IGN:localidad',       transparent: 'true',       format: 'image/png'      }" options="{isBaseLayer: true}"/> 
    </layers>
  <scales values="[7500000, 5000000, 2500000,  1000000, 750000, 500000, 250000, 100000, 75000, 50000, 25000, 10000, 7500, 5000, 2500, 1000]"/>
  <!--scales values="[]" /-->    
  <proj>
    <crs code="EPSG:4326" default="1" name="WGS84 (lat/lon)"/>
  </proj>
  <servers>
    <server name="NASA JPL OneEarth Web Mapping Server (WMS)" url="http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi?"/>
    <server name="NASA Earth Observations (NEO) WMS" url="http://neowms.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/wms/wms?"/>
    <server name="DEMIS World Map Server" url="http://www2.demis.nl/mapserver/wms.asp?"/>
    <server name="IDEF servicio WMS" url="http://idef.formosa.gob.ar/servicios/wms?"/>
  </servers>
 </mapViewer>
```

Hope this helps.
Regards

Cristian

Comment: @dblanchett after placing the geoserver war file in webapps I am able to open geonetwork. But after removing geoserver from webapps it is working